# Connect to remote docker host

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have following scenario.

1. Two Machine ( Physical Machine)
2. One is Windows 10 With Docker On Windows Installer and same way ubuntu 18.04 with docker-ce installed.
3. I can run command on individual and that is fine.
4. I want to connect Ubuntu Docker Host from Docker on Windows machine. So Docker CLI on Windows Point to deamon at Ubuntu Host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to enable docker remote API on Ubuntu Docker Host by adding below settings in daemon.json or your startup script

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "hosts": [ "unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376" ]
}
```

Once you restart docker you can connect to docker host locally by socket file and remotely by listening port (2376).
Verify the listening port of docker on Ubuntu

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -ntlp | grep 2376
tcp6       0      0 :::2376                 :::*                    LISTEN      1169/dockerd
```

Now you can connect to this docker from Windows machine by setting the DOCKER_HOST env variable in Windows like this

```
PS C:\Users\YellowDog> set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<Ubuntu-Docker_Host-IP>:2376
PS C:\Users\YellowDog> docker ps
```

It will list docker containers running on Ubuntu Docker Host

Comment: Though things are working but after change in daemon.json , when I do systemctl restart docker . It get failed. If I manually do dockerd then it seems working. Any Idea?

Comment: Can you check this log file(/var/log/daemon.log) where docker logs the error messages? It could be a syntax error.

Comment: You can follow below link for configuring daemon.json https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#configure-the-docker-daemon

Comment: Remember that **anyone** who can reach your system **can trivially root it** if you enable this option.  `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://...:2376 docker run -v/:/host busybox cat /etc/shadow` will get the lightly-encrypted user passwords, for instance.

Comment: you need also add file  /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf
see
https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#troubleshoot-the-daemon

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this through additional options to the service:

1. Find original `ExecStart` line docker.service:

```bash
systemctl status docker | grep load | grep -oP "\/.+service"
# -->  /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
cat /lib/systemd/system/docker.service | grep ExecStart
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
```

2. Create a new file to store the daemon options:

```bash
sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/
```

3. Add next lines with `-H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` options to `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/options.conf`:

```bash
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/options.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// \$DOCKER_OPTS -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
EOF
```

Here you need to pay attention to the escaping `$DOCKER_OPTS` variable if it exists.
Or using your favorite editor, for example vim.

4. Now, reload the systemd daemon and restart the docker service:

```bash
# Reload the systemd daemon.
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

# Restart Docker.
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

5. Configuring your dev box to connect to the remote Docker daemon:

If you want to set `DOCKER_HOST` by default so it always connects remotely you can export it in your `~/.bashrc` file.
Here’s an example of that as a 1 liner:

```bash
echo "export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://X.X.X.X:2375" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Or use it all at once:

```bash
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://X.X.X.X:2375 docker ps
```