# Remote to docker host daemon.json set up problem

Tags: docker

I have a docker desktop installed on my windows client but I want to connect to a Linux host server where I have docker and some containers running

When I do what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885910/connect-to-remote-docker-host) or in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#troubleshoot-the-daemon) and create a daemon.json

```
root@Docker:/etc/docker# systemctl daemon-reload
root@Docker:/etc/docker# systemctl restart docker.service
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@Docker:/etc/docker# dockerd
INFO[2022-05-21T22:15:44.911000210Z] Starting up 
WARN[2022-05-21T22:27:16.421785866Z] Binding to IP address without --tlsverify is insecure and gives root access on this machine to everyone who has access to your network.  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
WARN[2022-05-21T22:27:16.421811753Z] Binding to an IP address, even on localhost, can also give access to scripts run in a browser. Be safe out there!  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
WARN[2022-05-21T22:27:17.421973948Z] Binding to an IP address without --tlsverify is deprecated. Startup is intentionally being slowed down to show this message  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
WARN[2022-05-21T22:27:17.422102835Z] Please consider generating tls certificates with client validation to prevent exposing unauthenticated root access to your network  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
WARN[2022-05-21T22:27:17.422151726Z] You can override this by explicitly specifying '--tls=false' or '--tlsverify=false'  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
WARN[2022-05-21T22:27:17.422199210Z] Support for listening on TCP without authentication or explicit intent to run without authentication will be removed in the next release  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:32.427159372Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:32.427252568Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:32.427313370Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:32.427344997Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:32.434202191Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:32.434266723Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:32.434321187Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:32.434350739Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:32.442793741Z] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2 
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:32.460473338Z] Loading containers: start.                   
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:32.677853303Z] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:33.205926671Z] Loading containers: done.                    
WARN[2022-05-21T22:27:33.222645712Z] Not using native diff for overlay2, this may cause degraded performance for building images: running in a user namespace  storage-driver=overlay2
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:33.222936503Z] Docker daemon                                 commit=75249d8 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.8
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:33.222997151Z] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:33.260295863Z] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock           
INFO[2022-05-21T22:27:33.271850141Z] API listen on [::]:2376
```

a reboot of the docker service throws an error.
though docker**d** is starting up manually, then I am stuck in the console
While I am still not able to connect from my windows machine. Even after setting

```
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<Ubuntu-Docker_Host-IP>:2376
```

and restarting docker desktop, with "docker ps -a" it only shows me local containers.

Comment: Have you tried using contexts? https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/

Comment: The "is insecure" message is really really important: you've opened up a path for _anyone_ with network access to your system to trivially get unrestricted root-level access to the whole host.  Has your system been compromised (search for "Docker cryptojacking")?

Comment: The host is just an empty VM with docker. But thanks. I have deleted the daemon.json again anyways cause it didn't work. How else do you connect to a remote docker host?